# How do I create a recursive task in SP 2013 without SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Everyday an employee manually checks off he that he completed a draft invoice and a final invoice.  I want to set up 2 tasks in SharePoint that are recursive..everyday the user would be notified a list of 2 tasks to be completed..

Any suggestions

When I google it it seems I need SP Designer, but our company does not allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Visual Studio workflows, there is no way to do this with Sharepoint Out of the box, you need a customized workflow.